# Add new fieldset elements with button click

Tags: javascript

Is there any way with JavaScript to generate all the elements in the fieldset with the click of a button? Code below shows two textboxes and one textarea in a fieldset.When I press 'Add item button',I would like to generate the same textboxes and textarea within that fieldset.

Many thanks for your help.

```
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<legend id="legend">Professional development</legend>
<p>Item                     <input type ="text" size="25"   name="prof_item" /><br /></p>
<p>Duration                 <input type ="text" size="25"   name="prof_duration" /><br /></p>
<p>Enlargement              <label for="enlargement"></label><p></p>
                            <textarea name="textarea" cols="71" rows="5" id="prof_enlargement">
</textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add new item" id="add_prof" /></p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clone them. First wrap those elements with parent `div` call it for example "template":

```
<div id="template">
  <p>Item <input type ="text" size="25" name="prof_item" /><br /></p>
  <p>Duration <input type ="text" size="25" name="prof_duration" /><br /></p>
  <p>Enlargement <label for="enlargement"></label></p>
   <p><textarea name="prof_enlargement" cols="71" rows="5" id=""></textarea></p>
</div>
```

Second have placeholder that will contain all the clones you add:

```
<div id="placeholder">
  <div id="template">
     <p>Item <input type ="text" size="25" name="prof_item" /><br /></p>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And finally this JS code will add the elements in there:

```
var _counter = 0;
function Add() {
    _counter++;
    var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
    oClone.id += (_counter + "");
    document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
}
```

Just call the function "Add" in the button click event.. the counter is required to avoid having same ID for more than one element.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/eW6j4/

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.It works very well now. @Shadow Wizard

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#fieldset').clone().insertAfter($('#fieldset'));
});
```

Try something like this, Clone() is useful
http://api.jquery.com/clone/

-edited after your comment-
Add this to your htmlpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_prof').click(function() {
            $('#fieldset').clone().insertAfter($('#fieldset'));
    });
});
</script>
```

-edited again after your comment-

In order to let the function work on newly added inputs as well, we use 'live'. the .click that I suggested works on the elements when the code is executed. When we use .live, the function will be executed with every existing element that you selected, but also with future elements of your selection. Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('fieldset input').live('click',function() {
            $(this).parent('fieldset').clone().insertAfter($(this).parent('fieldset'));
    });
});
</script>
```

If the code works, please mark this answer as 'accepted answer' so other users with the same question can immediately see the working code.

Comment: @rsplak Where in the code shall I put your extract?I tried to put before and after </fieldset> inside <script> tags but nothing happens when I click the button.I did enable jquery in the <head> of the document, but still nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It works very well but how can I make it work so that the button works again on the cloned fieldset? @rsplak

Comment: Thanks for your answer once again.The thing is I have four different fieldsets named as such:<fieldset id="fieldset4">.How can make it work of all four fieldsets?My previous code was done like so:<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_prof').click(function() {
            $('#fieldset4').clone().insertAfter($('#fieldset4'));
    });
});
</script>  @rsplak

Comment: The last edit I made doesn't select by ID's, just by element type. I figured you wanted this so I did it differently than the previous update. This time I use $(this).parent('fieldset') to see which fieldset to clone when you click the input. After that, I add the fieldset after the fieldset you clicked.Try the code, good luck :)

Comment: Still it doesn't work.I'm sorry that I keep bothering you so much.I really don't know what the problem is.I was only able to make it work previously for each fieldset with id specified for each one like <fieldset id="fieldset4>. @rsplak

Answer (score 0):

i prefer javascript way

```
var fieldset= document.getElementById('fieldset');
var fieldParent = fieldset.parentNode;
var newFieldSet = document.createElement('fieldset');
newFieldSet.innerHTML = fieldset.innerHTML;
fieldParent.appendChild(newFieldSet);
```

Regards :)

Comment: Cloning the element is better than assigning the same inner HTML, but your idea *is* good.